# Notification is Only Triggering in the Lock Model in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, push-notification, alarm, localnotification

I am **triggering Local Notification** in my iOS app. I am getting the notification only when the device is locked. I want the notification to **show on top** of my app.

I am triggering notification with the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
   
        Button {
                    
           let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
           content.title = "Cold Water Therapy"
           content.body = "Timer ended"
        
           content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "iphone_alarm_morning.mp3"))
        
           let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        
           let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
         
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)

          } label: {
               Text("Trigger notification")
          }
   }
}
```

I am getting the notification when the device is locked with the **default sound**.

How can I get notification on top of my **app** with **UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "iphone_alarm_morning.mp3")** sound?

Comment: By default local notifications are only delivered when your app is not in the foreground (the device should not need to be locked). To see notifications when your app is in the foreground you need to implement a delegate method on the UserNotificationCenter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782435/receive-local-notifications-within-own-app-view-or-how-to-register-a-unuserno